# How do I replace an existing Singleton object with one from a saved file using ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java, singleton, ioexception, objectinputstream

I'm making a Java application that has basic Saving / Opening capabilities. All I need to save is the instance of my class **ModeleImage** which is a Singleton. My saving apparently works and looks like this:

```
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
outputStream.writeObject(ModeleImage.getInstance());
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Now I'm trying to open that file with ObjectInputStream. I'm not sure if there's a way to simply replace my Singleton (ModeleImage) with the saved one but right now I'm only trying to copy and replace each attribute. My opening looks like this:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

//Get each attribute from the file and set them in my existing ModeleImage Singleton

ModeleImage.getInstance().setImage(((ModeleImage) ois.readObject()).getImage());
ModeleImage.getInstance().setLargeurImage(((ModeleImage) ois.readObject()).getLargeurImage());
ModeleImage.getInstance().setHauteurImage(((ModeleImage) ois.readObject()).getHauteurImage());
ModeleImage.getInstance().setxImage(((ModeleImage) ois.readObject()).getxImage());
ModeleImage.getInstance().setyImage(((ModeleImage) ois.readObject()).getyImage());
```

I also put try/catch around each. The problem is that my opening part catches an IOException when trying to replace attributes.

```
ModeleImage.getInstance().setImage(((ModeleImage) ois.readObject()).getImage());
//This catches an IOException
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is it because it's a Singleton or am I misunderstanding how ObjectInputStream and readObject() work?

Comment: EDIT: Actually I just found out my serialization simply doesn't work when I'm trying to save. I tried opening my saved file with a text editor and it starts with:

`java.io.NotSerializableException`

Comment: EDIT 2: I forgot to implement Serializable in my ModeleImage class. Now the saved file has no error but is tiny (205 bytes) and contains the name of the fields but not their value. One of the field is an image so the file should be pretty big.

Answer (score 1):

By using a built-in feature of the serialization mechanism, you can enhance the normal process by providing two methods inside class file. Those methods are:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException;
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

Implement this methods by ModeleImage class and you will control all aspects of serialization and have access to internal state of singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You should only be calling `readObject()` once since you only wrote one object:

```
ModeleImage image = ois.readObject();
ModeleImage.getInstance().setImage((image.getImage());
ModeleImage.getInstance().setLargeurImage(image.getLargeurImage());
ModeleImage.getInstance().setHauteurImage((image.getHauteurImage());
ModeleImage.getInstance().setxImage(image.getxImage());
ModeleImage.getInstance().setyImage(image.getyImage());
```

Comment: the problem is that I would create a new instance of ModeleImage which is a Singleton, and I'm trying to avoid that to not break the Singleton pattern.

Comment: You are already breaking the Singleton pattern by deserializing one of these of course.  So you'd like to update the fields in your singleton with the fields from the deserialized object?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I just found out my saving is probably the problem. I get a `java.io.NotSerializableException` error in the file that is saved.

Comment: Make sure that ModeleImage implements Serializable of course.  Either way, you will have to solve the problem.  Do you want the new object to _replace_ your singleton or to copy all of its fields?

Comment: Either. I decided to copy the fields because I thought it was more simple like that.

I was in fact not implementing Serializable but now I notice the saved file is tiny (205 bytes) and contains the name of the fields but no value.

Comment: All of the subfields also need to implement Serializable.  Might want to read some docs: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is have a static block that checks an instance of your class that you serialized. If it can, find it, it sets it to your singleton instance (thus making sure you load the one from the file). If it can't find it (perhaps first time your program is launching), then it should create an instance and assign it to your singleton variable.

You could create a save method or what not, or override the finalize method to save off your singleton so that way you can check for it in the static block on next time it is class loaded.

Make sense?

Comment: Although I would question why you want to store state in a singleton. That could get very messy. You may actually want to use a Properties file or something else. Perhaps have a class that is managed by your singleton that stores the state. Then you can get around serializing a singleton and yet get the data once as you need.

Comment: I'm beginning in Java and it was the first time I used Singletons in an application. Obviously this one shouldn't have been one and it doesn't need to been one either so I don't mind breaking the Singleton pattern, I just want it to store a state without rethinking everything. Now my problem only seems to be my use of ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream. I don't know much about serialization so it doesn't help.

Comment: Well, don't take this the wrong way, but if you are a learner in Java, you shouldn't break a design pattern. No one really should. It is a pattern for a reason. To break it, deviates from the fact that it was a design pattern. Again, don't take this the wrong way. Just trying to help coach you.

Answer (score 0):

Implement readResolve on your serializable Singleton class to ensure there is only ever a single instance and override the properties there, i.e.

```
private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException
{
    instance.setImage(getImage());
    instance.setLargeurImage(getLargeurImage());
    ... 
    return instance;
}
```

this concept is described nicely on http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17491.html or check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/serialization/spec/input.doc6.html for more on readResolve(). Hope that helps.